# Angular2/http Exception no ConnectionBackend

Tags: http, service, angular

I attempting to use an angular2 http request, but I am getting the following error:
[Error] EXCEPTION: No provider for ConnectionBackend! (AppComponent -> Http -> ConnectionBackend)

I have setup a barebones app which has the same problem, and am at a loss to what is causing it.

Thanks in advance

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="getEmployee()">Get</button>
    <p>{{employee.email}}</p>

  `,
  providers: [Http]
})

export class AppComponent {
  employee: {"email": "bob"};
  http: Http;

  constructor(http:Http){
    this.http = http;
  }

  getEmployee(){
    this.http.get('localhost:8080/employee-rates?id=0')
      .map(response => response.json()).subscribe(result => this.employee = result);
  }


}
```

main.ts

```
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, HTTP_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS, HTTP_BINDINGS
]);
```

index.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="js/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="js/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="js/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <div class='small-12'>
      <app>Loading...</app>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: [here is a new answer]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098413/angular-2-no-provider-for-connectionbackend

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove `HTTP_BINDINGS` from your code. They are deprecated and reference `HTTP_PROVIDERS`, so it's like you're using providers twice.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Also you don't need `providers: [Http]` in your component, since you injected `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in bootstrap. Adding it to the component's providers will create new instance of the service.

```
@Component({
  providers: []
})
```

Comment: Just tested this and unfortunately the issue persists.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO!

Comment: `HTTP_PROVIDERS` is no longer a thing

Answer (score 20):

From Angular 2 RC5 version, in your NgModule file, add:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        ...
        HttpModule ]
```

Comment: why import and not provide?

Comment: @Markus, because `HttpModule` is a **module** (not a service) and it has to be imported.

Comment: Yap. this is the way. I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

src/main.ts

```
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, ConnectionBackend } from '@angular/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ConnectionBackend
]);
```

Using **angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.10** and **angular@2.0.0-rc.4**

Comment: any idea in final production release?