# Injecting http in a service gives "No provider for Http!" error

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Angular version: 2.0.0-beta.13

I am trying to inject `http` into a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class GithubService {
    ...
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }
}
```

I have listed `HTTP_PROVIDERS` as a provider in the root component of my application, so this provider should be available to any component in my application:

```
@Component({
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

However when I run this application, I get the following error:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for Http! (HttpReqComponent -> GithubService -> Http)

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I changed `providers` to `viewProviders` and the error is now gone!

```
@Component({
  viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

However, I cannot explain why this is working. `http` is not being accessed by any view directly. It is only accessed inside `GithubService`. So why do I have to declare `HTTP_PROVIDERS` as a `viewProvider`?

**Edit 2**

Well, I moved the `providers` declaration from AppComponent down to the component where I need it and now it works! So there must be some quirk in declaring it at the root level.

```
@Component({
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, GithubService],
})
export class HttpReqComponent { }
```

Actually, both `providers` and `viewProviders` works. Turns out that `viewProviders` is actually more restrictive and provides better encapsulation of the component. See [this article](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/) for details.

Comment: You don't need viewProvider, actually I search for it and didn't find any reference, but I tested and it works with **providers** and also with **viewProviders** . If you are still unsure create a plunker code app to see exactly.

Comment: That's really strange because it should work. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/gG84YnQPItRSf0tIJSMK?p=preview. I'd be interested in knowing more about your environment ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its okay if you go with `Providers:[HTTP_PROVIDERS]` but its good to refernce `HTTP_PROVIDERS` into `bootstrap()`. You don't need to use `viewProvider`, it is there for some other purpose.

you have to make sure that `http.dev.js` has been included (via CDN/node_modules).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.13/http.dev.js"></script>
```

Then in **rootComponent**,

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {GithubService} from './GithubService';

bootstrap(rootComponent,[HTTP_PROVIDERS,GithubService]);

// if you reference HTTP_PROVIDERS here globally (in bootstrap), you don't require to use providers:[HTTP_PROVIDERS] in any component. 
// same way GithubService reference has been passed globally which would create single instance of GithubService (In case if you want)
```

Then in **GithubService** ,

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class GithubService {
    ...
    constructor(private http: Http) {  // this will work now without any error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @micronyks. AFAIK, Angular 2 documentation discourages the use of bootstrap for registering providers (see [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)). I have solved the issue now by moving the registration to the component that needs it. Please see my *Edit 2*.

Comment: I also read that ;-) I don't think that it applies for providers from Angular2 like `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` or `HTTP_PROVIDERS`. I think the comment is to restrict the scope of providers in your application. It's "just" a way to organize your application. That said I think that there are use cases when it's necessary to define some of your services when bootstrapping your application. For example, when you want to have a shared service for different parts.

Comment: @micronyks, I found another reference that also suggests not to use bootstrap for registering providers: see [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-style-guide#services-and-dependency-injection). For now I will be sticking with that advice. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am marking your answer correct because your basic statement that providers and viewProviders should both work is indeed correct.

Answer (score 20):

Following this link

[Angular2/http Exception no ConnectionBackend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586874/angular2-http-exception-no-connectionbackend)
The answer of @abreneliere is correct for me while working with Angular 2 Quickstart (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) and i was trying to add a service to a component.

The answer:
File: app.module.ts 
Code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This did the trick for me using `@angular/http: ~2.4.0`. Simple solution. Cheers!

Comment: Worked like a charm !!  :)

Comment: Worked on Nativescript 3.0.0! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

As of `2.0.0-rc.5` this is now:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule
  ]}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

You can import `{ HttpModule }` into a module that has your component declared, in which you are using injectable service, given module is not lazy loaded.