# angular 4 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ConnectionBackend! while injecting Jsonp

Tags: angular

When i am trying to inject Jsonp, i am seeing this error

***Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ConnectionBackend!
Error: No provider for ConnectionBackend!
at Error (native)***

**My home.component.ts file**

```
import { NgModule, Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule, Jsonp, Response, URLSearchParams, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    providers: [HttpModule, JsonpModule, Jsonp]
})

@Injectable()
export class HomeComponent {
    public jsonp: Jsonp;
    constructor(jsonp: Jsonp) {
        this.jsonp = jsonp;
    }
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: You will need to add `HttpModule` to the `imports` array in your root module (probably `app.module.ts`) not the providers of the component. Since Angular rc5 `providers` should not be in the `@Component`

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098413/angular-2-no-provider-for-connectionbackend

Answer (score 2):

`providers` array can only have `Injectable` not `modules`

```
providers: [HttpModule, JsonpModule, Jsonp]
```

should be

```
providers: [Jsonp]
```

Also make sure you should include `HttpModule, JsonpModule` in `imports` NgModule of your `AppModule`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have modified **home.component.ts** as you suggested by removing **HttpModule and JsonpModule** from providers and add them in **NgModule**, but still i am seeing same error.

Comment: @SrinivasAdumulla can you create a plunker of the same?

Answer (score 0):

You miss import `JsonpModule` in your `app.module.ts`, in the next lines I show you, where you should import  `JsonpModule` .

**app.module.ts**

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
    import { HomeComponent }  from './yourComponentFolder/home.component'

    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```