# No provider for connection backend

Tags: angular, angular6

I was trying to use my `services` classes in `components` , I did not get any compilation error, but got below error in browser console

> ng:///CoreModule/LayoutComponent.ngfactory.js:418 ERROR Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ConnectionBackend]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ConnectionBackend]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ConnectionBackend!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 : No provider for ConnectionBackend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098413/angular-2-no-provider-for-connectionbackend)

Answer (score 1):

Import the **HttpModule** in your module. The **HttpModule** registers providers for all its services.

```
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
 imports: [HttpModule], 
 declarations: [
        // Your components
  ],
  providers: [
    // your services

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide service if you want to use it.to add service in app.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [], 
  declarations: [],
  providers: [ConnectionBackend], <- add here your service
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```