# Ionic2 : No provider for ConnectionBackend?

Tags: ionic2, angular2-services

I am trying to read json file data to my Html page, but getting 'No provider for ConnectionBackend!

See below code

> **Home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController ,Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { SampleDataService } from '../../providers/sample-data-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  myjsondata:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform,
  sampleDataService:SampleDataService) {
                sampleDataService.getJsonData().subscribe((data) => {
                console.log("what is in the data ", data);
                this.myjsondata = data;
              });    
  }  

  ngOnInit(){}
}
```

> **app.component.ts**

```
import { SampleDataService } from '../providers/sample-data-service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers:[SampleDataService,Http]

})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar,
     public splashScreen: SplashScreen, sampleDataService:SampleDataService,
     http:Http) {
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    sampleDataService.getJsonData();

    this.initializeApp();
```

> **app.module.ts**

```
import { SampleDataService } from '../providers/sample-data-service';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    About,
    Contact,
    AboutCity
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    //AutoCompleteModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    About,
    Contact,
    AboutCity
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    SampleDataService,
    Http
  ]
})
```

I tried a lot but not getting solution why this error is. 
Can please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `HttpModule` in the `imports` section in the `app.module.ts`
Also, remove the `Http` from the providers.

```
import { SampleDataService } from '../providers/sample-data-service';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    About,
    Contact,
    AboutCity
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    //AutoCompleteModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    About,
    Contact,
    AboutCity
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    SampleDataService,

  ]
})
```

Please see this [highly voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39249784/5079380) as well.